# white space on blurring image

Tags: html, css

After adding a blur effect to the background in HTML, I noticed that there is a small white space that appeared on top and a huge one on the left of the image. I need the image to be stretched to fit the screen in all dimensions. Can someone please help?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fit image on screen</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Henny+Penny?query=nf' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body:before {
      background-image: url('pexels-pixabay-270360.jpg');
      content: '';
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
      -moz-filter: blur(1px);
      -o-filter: blur(1px);
      -ms-filter: blur(1px);
      filter: blur(1px);
      z-index: -9;
      /* width: auto; */
      margin: 0;
      /* padding:0; */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `body{margin:0;padding:0;}`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fit image on screen</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Henny+Penny?query=nf' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body:before {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200');
      content: '';
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
      -moz-filter: blur(1px);
      -o-filter: blur(1px);
      -ms-filter: blur(1px);
      filter: blur(1px);
      z-index: -9;
      /* width: auto; */
      margin: 0;
      /* padding:0; */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```